# Cant enter raw_parser in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to analyze how postgreSQL parse a query, and after some postgreSQL source code tracing with embedding printf() here and there, I've known that the query will be parsed into raw parse tree with raw_parser, which located in file parser.c.

The strange thing is, I've already embedded a printf() dummy in the raw_parser, and after re-installing the postgreSQL and execute a query, my printf() dummy is not printed to the screen!

Can anybody please help me, where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: One possibility is that the handle for stdout has been closed or changed to something you don't expect. Try opening your own file and writing to that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use printf(stderr, "...."), then you can find result in server log. Don't forget - you are not work with server directly. For debugging purposes there are a elog function - it's like printf for client application:

```
elog(NOTICE, "some text");
```

a format string is same like printf's format - but you must to remember, PostgreSQL uses a different formats than glibc - so you can to show only integer or float variables. String variables uses different format than is C zero finished string.